# How to find the local perforce depot path?

Tags: perforce

I am trying to write a maven compile command and want it to work on my colleagues' machines as well, and since they have a different perforce depot path than mine, I need a unified way to find it.

I have tried p4 where but it didn't help.

Comment: `p4 where` will have to help. How is it not helping?

Comment: How do they have a different depot path if you're both connecting to the same depot?  Including a bit of example with your question might help.

Comment: @sferencik, using p4 where is returning :

//depot/... //XXXX/depot/... c:\Users\XXXX\depot\... 

whereas my depot is under D: , not C:

Comment: @SamStafford, some people choose to have their workspace under D:/depot, others for example D:/perforce/depot

Comment: The "depot path" is //depot/... which is the same in both cases -- what you're asking about is the workspace path (D:\depot or whatever).

Answer (score 3):

When you run the `p4 where` command make sure that you're using the correct client workspace.

E.g.:

```
p4 set P4CLIENT=my_client_name
p4 where //depot/...
```

or:

```
p4 -c my_client_name where //depot/...
```

The example you describe of `p4 where` returning the wrong path indicates that it's giving the answer in terms of a different client workspace.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

The question is this:
How do I programmatically determine "my_client_name"?

Comment: If everything is configured correctly, Perforce determines it programmatically all on its own.  If things aren't configured correctly, you need to correct the configuration, e.g. as described above.